# MySQL get data older than 30 minutes and perform some tasks

Tags: php, mysql, function, coupon

I am trying to make a coupon system, but I got stuck with something. I want to make a function that gets all data from coupon_session where the time (datetime) is older than 30 minutes. For each of the results, I want to fetch the "code" from the row, and after that I want it to delete the row.

I've already figured out how to retrieve the data, but the rest is kinda hard for me. Could you guys help a bit?

This is my code for fetching all > 30 min old rows:

```
mysql_query("GET * FROM `coupon_session` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,time,NOW()) > 30");
```

Comment: Are you at all familiar with SQL/MySQL syntax?

Comment: Is "Get *" working for you? I've never seen this before. Are you really sure it's working?

Comment: I think you want `SELECT`, not `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

The code to fetch what you want is:

```
select cs.code
from coupon_session cs
where time < date_sub(now(), interval 30 minute);
```

Deleting is another problem, because the value of `now()` changes.  You have several choices, such as:

- Get the list of ids to delete in your application and delete those (probably the safest method).
- Calculate "now" in your application and use the same value for the `select` and `delete` (also safe).
- Calculate the maximum time returned by the `select` and use that for the subsequent delete.

Comment: Doesn't that question return times that is at most 30 minutes old? OP wanted "older than 30 minutes"... or am I missing something fundamental?